# Why are linear maps/transformations usually written with bases for the matrix representation?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $T\in L(V,W)$, and we want the matrix representation, why do we usually choose to write $T$ in terms of the basis vectors of $V$ and $W$? Thanks!

Comment: if $V,W$ are finite dimensional.. cuz employing matrix multiplication you can map easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the basis of a vector space gives a lot of information about that space (in fact, it gives all the information you could hope for, since if two vector spaces over the same field have the same basis, they are isomorphic, and algebraically, the same object). This makes studying the way a linear map affects a basis the best way to understand the global behaviour of that map.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior on a basis dictates the behavior everywhere else, for a linear function.

So for example in finite dimensional real vector spaces, you don't have to think about infinitely many vectors being mapped. You can just focus on the finitely many in the basis, and the rest sort themselves out.